# Using setSpanSizeLookup with StaggeredGridLayoutmanager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, staggeredgridlayout

When I try to use setSpanSizeLookup with GridLayoutManager, it works without error. However, using the same setSpanSizeLookup with StaggeredGridLayoutManager gives an error. It isn't a valid class apparently. Is there any way to use setSpanSizeLookup with StaggeredGridLayoutManager or could you suggest an alternative solution to achieve the same result?

Here is how I have used setSpanSizeLookup with GridLayoutManager -

```
GridLayoutManager llm = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
         llm.setSpanSizeLookup(new SpanSizeLookup() {

            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                if(position == 0)
                {
                    return 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 1;
                }
        }
});
```

Essentially I want to set the span size of the first item to be maximum and the subsequent rows to be half. Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is very similar to mine, it has an answer that helped me and will probably help you if you still are looking for an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696096/setting-span-size-of-single-row-in-staggeredgridlayoutmanager/33707897#33707897

Answer (score 2):

how this
in adapter implements:

```
@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
    if(lp != null
            && lp instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams
            && holder.getLayoutPosition() == 0) {
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams p = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) lp;
        p.setFullSpan(true);
    }
}
```