# Android Staggered Grdiv View last element full screen if standalone

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I have the following recycler view with Staggered Grid Layout Manager:

[image]

I would like to adapt each item of the staggered grid view like this (the last element full-screen if its stand alone) :

[image]

Main.java:

```
   staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    superEffectiveRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    effectivenessSuperEffectiveAdapter = new EffectivenessRecyclerAdapter(this, effectivenessesSuperEffective);
    superEffectiveRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    superEffectiveRecyclerView.setAdapter(effectivenessSuperEffectiveAdapter);
```

list_item_type.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/effectiveness_effect"
    android:layout_width="33dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/placeholder"
    android:textColor="#f000"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/effectiveness_name"
    android:layout_width="81dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/placeholder"
    android:textColor="#f000"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

content_main.xml:

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/super_efective_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"  />
```

How Can I achieve this ?

EDIT : apparently , setting :

```
     StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
    if(Objects.nonNull(layoutParams)){
        if (getItemCount() % 3 == 1 && position == getItemCount() - 1) {
            layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
        }
    }
```

In view holder results in this :

[image]

However , this is not exactly what I want , I only want the last element fullscreen

Comment: to be clear you want the last element full-screen if its stand alone. right?

Comment: @JyotishBiswas Yes , exactly

Comment: did you check `staggeredGridLayoutManager.setFullSpan(true);`?

Comment: @hassanmoradnezhad check my update question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
public final void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    if (size % 2 == 1 && position == size - 1) {
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
    }
}
```

Reference [Setting span size of single row in StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696096/setting-span-size-of-single-row-in-staggeredgridlayoutmanager)

## EDIT

You can also try gridlayout if you want
set this when you set layoutManager to your recyclerview
and size = size of your list which you pass in your adapter

```
 gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            // 3 is the sum of items in one repeated section
            if (size%2==1&&position==size-1)
                return 1;
            else return 2;
            throw new IllegalStateException("internal error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: From where I get the size ?

Comment: here size is what you returns in  getItemCount

Comment: did you add this filter  `if (size % 2 == 1 && position == size - 1)` ?

Comment: then you should use Simple Gridlayout if you don't have any problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218424/discussion-between-jyotish-biswas-and-nexussim-lements).